# In Python, Pandas is loading CSV file incorrectly (Python for Data Analysis book example)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm following the Python for Data Analysis book. It tells me to get the ALL file from http://www.fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do and load it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

fec = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv')
```

But the actual file has changed since the book was written. The old file (which is available here https://github.com/pydata/pydata-book/blob/master/ch09/P00000001-ALL.csv) loads just fine

```
fec = pd.read_csv('../pydata-book/ch09/P00000001-ALL.csv')
```

**But the new one is loaded wrong, in that the columns seem to have shifted (the first column value is dropped)**

```
cmte_id                           P60008059
cand_id                           Bush, Jeb
cand_nm              EASTON, AMY KELLY MRS.
contbr_nm                      KEY BISCAYNE
contbr_city                              FL
contbr_st                         331491716
contbr_zip                        HOMEMAKER
contbr_employer                   HOMEMAKER
contbr_occupation                      2700
contb_receipt_amt                 26-JUN-15
contb_receipt_dt                        NaN
receipt_desc                            NaN
memo_cd                                 NaN
memo_text                             SA17A
form_tp                             1024106
file_num                        SA17.114991
tran_id                               P2016
election_tp                             NaN
```

The actual row is

```
C00579458,"P60008059","Bush, Jeb","EASTON, AMY KELLY MRS.","KEY BISCAYNE","FL","331491716","HOMEMAKER","HOMEMAKER",2700,26-JUN-15,"","","","SA17A","1024106","SA17.114991","P2016",
```

So that C00579458 is lost somewhere.

The header looks like this.
    cmte_id,cand_id,cand_nm,contbr_nm,contbr_city,contbr_st,contbr_zip,contbr_employer,contbr_occupation,contb_receipt_amt,contb_receipt_dt,receipt_desc,memo_cd,memo_text,form_tp,file_num,tran_id,election_tp

Comment: Can you add few rows including header of the csv causing issue and the exact output you are getting for those rows.

Comment: Hi Anand, you have the header and one row above? Do you need me to add a few more rows?

Comment: when you check your dataframe, is the first element being considered as index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer already suggess , you have malformed csv with a `comma` at the end of the row. Hence, this causes pandas to consider the first column as the index column.

To workaround this, you can pass `index_col=False` argument to [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function. Example -

```
In [24]: s = io.StringIO("""cmte_id,cand_id,cand_nm,contbr_nm,contbr_city,contbr_st,contbr_zip,contbr_employer,contbr_occupation,contb_receipt_amt,contb_receipt_dt,receipt_desc,memo_cd,memo_text,form_tp,file_num,tran_id,election_tp
   ....: C00579458,"P60008059","Bush, Jeb","EASTON, AMY KELLY MRS.","KEY BISCAYNE","FL","331491716","HOMEMAKER","HOMEMAKER",2700,26-JUN-15,"","","","SA17A","1024106","SA17.114991","P2016",""")

In [25]: df = pd.read_csv(s)  #Issue

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
             cmte_id    cand_id                 cand_nm     contbr_nm  \
C00579458  P60008059  Bush, Jeb  EASTON, AMY KELLY MRS.  KEY BISCAYNE

          contbr_city  contbr_st contbr_zip contbr_employer  \
C00579458          FL  331491716  HOMEMAKER       HOMEMAKER

           contbr_occupation contb_receipt_amt  contb_receipt_dt  \
C00579458               2700         26-JUN-15               NaN

           receipt_desc  memo_cd memo_text  form_tp     file_num tran_id  \
C00579458           NaN      NaN     SA17A  1024106  SA17.114991   P2016

           election_tp
C00579458          NaN

In [29]: df = pd.read_csv(s,index_col=False)  #No issue

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
     cmte_id    cand_id    cand_nm               contbr_nm   contbr_city  \
0  C00579458  P60008059  Bush, Jeb  EASTON, AMY KELLY MRS.  KEY BISCAYNE

  contbr_st  contbr_zip contbr_employer contbr_occupation  contb_receipt_amt  \
0        FL   331491716       HOMEMAKER         HOMEMAKER               2700

  contb_receipt_dt  receipt_desc  memo_cd  memo_text form_tp  file_num  \
0        26-JUN-15           NaN      NaN        NaN   SA17A   1024106

       tran_id election_tp
0  SA17.114991       P2016
```

This is explained correctly in [the documentations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) -

> `index_col` : int or sequence or False, default None
>
> Column to use as the row labels of the DataFrame. If a sequence is given, a MultiIndex is used. **If you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of each line, you might consider index_col=False to force pandas to *not* use the first column as the index (row names)**

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra comma in the end of each row in the raw data.

```
C00458844,"P60006723","Rubio, Marco","HEFFERNAN, MICHAEL","APO","AE","090960009","INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS","INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS",210,27-JUN-15,"","","","SA17A","1015697","SA17.796904","P2016",
```

If you have 2 commas, each row would shift by 2 columns.

Comment: Aha! So the source file is corrupt! Gayatri, is there a way to fix this with Pandas (tell it about the columns or something)? Thanks.